# Decrease space between controls in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, flowlayoutpanel

How can I decrease the space between the controls even further?
I've set all the margins and padding to 0 but there is still space between my controlers.

[image: flow layout properties]

this is the space I am getting with all margins and padding set to 0. I even set the margin and padding on each controller to 0.

[image: new spacing]

and for the sake of consistency here is the code that is adding the PictureBoxes

```
Dim newPic As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
newPic.Image = p.Image
newPic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(New Point(p.Size.Width * 2, 
                                                p.Size.Height * 2))
newPic.SizeMode = p.SizeMode
laytt.SetToolTip(newPic, ttstring)
AddHandler newPic.Click, AddressOf LayoutComponent_Clicked 

LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.Add(newPic)
```

Comment: Is it not enough for you if you set all margins of each contained control to 0?

Comment: I just tried that and it did decrease the space but there is still a space (2 pixels?) between them

Comment: new image added showing spacing

Comment: I still have a hard time guessing which controls you are using, and what is the end goal of yours, but see my answer - hope it clears things up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not setting the Margin property on the picture boxes you add.  The default is 3,3,3,3.  Add this line of code to fix the problem:

```
  newPic.Margin = New Padding(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Every control handles margins differently, even with standard controls. Have a look at this example:

[image]

Notice that a `Button` reserves some space around it, while a TextBox takes everything. You may ask why 2 pixels in between them which you can clearly see. For that - please copy/paste into Paint and zoom in. Those 2 pixels are in fact the border, this is how a control is drawn. I am sure `Buttons` also have a border, but it's harder to justify visually, even when zoomed in.

If you want to change that, you would need to create a custom control and override how it's drawn, i.e. manually cut borders from it or similar. But I would not recommend doing it, to keep UI consistent.